# by reference in C++

Tags: c++

I have this snippet of the code

```
Stack& Stack:: operator=(const Stack& stack){
   if(this == &stack){
      return *this
   }
}
```

here I define operator `=` but I can't understand, if I receive by reference stack why it should be `&` in `this == &stack` and not `this == stack` and why we return `*` in `return *this` and not `this` thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `this` is a pointer (i.e. of type `Stack*`), not a reference (i.e. not of type `Stack&`).

---

We use `if(this == &stack)` just to ensure the statement

```
 s = s;
```

can be handled correctly (especially when you need to delete something in the old object). The pointer comparison is true only when both are the same object. Of course, we could compare by value too

```
if (*this == stack)
  return *this;
else {
  ...
}
```

But the `==` operation can be very slow. For example, if your stack has N items, `*this == stack` will take N steps. As the assignment itself only takes N steps, this will double the effort for nothing.

Comment: Actually, it depends on what kind of comparison you want to do.  If you want to see if they're the same object, you do `this == &stack`, but if you want to check if they have equal values, regardless of whether they are the same object, you do `*this == stack`.

Comment: Seams the first question was meant to ask why we use & if we already get a reference as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

`stack` is of type `Stack&`, and `this` is of type `Stack*`. You're checking if the address of `stack` is equal to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

> if I receive by reference stack why it should be & in this == &stack

Because `this` is a pointer (or "address") and `stack` is a reference (not a pointer): so you need to say `&stack` (which means "address of stack"), so that its type matches the type of `this`.

> why we return * in return *this and not this

Because `this` is a pointer (not a reference), but the method is supposed to return a reference (not a pointer), so you need to deference it in order to turn the pointer into a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your two questions.

1. As I understand you ask why we use & sign if we get reference as a function parameter(not an abject). Because reference to an abject is not address of it. You should use operator&() in order to get the address of an object.
2. **this** is a pointer, but you should return reference thus you return ***this**